Is there a way to display monthly actuals & monthly budget figures in power BI matric, organised showing monthly actuals and budget amounts
The problem i have at the moment is that power BI matrix organises the data in such a way that time measure takes precedence and plots measures next to each other. If i have 2 measures i.e Actuals & Budget and combine this with date dimension i will have the following output:-
    Apr23       May23       Jun23    
    Act   Bud   Act   Bud   Act   Bud
    

I have simplified the above to show only 3 months of data, there should be 12 months April23 to Mar24 of actuals & budget data.
**Requirement **
Our users require a profiled actuals v plan matrix report where the measures are not plotted side by side next to each other and are treated as separate entities. We would have 12 months of actuals and 12 months budget data. The additional requirement is that we need to also show forecasted data on the same report.
  Apr23 May23 Jun23   Apr23 May23 Jun23  
    Act   Act   Act   Bud   Bud   Bud

I have tried different ideas in terms of presenting the data in the required format.
We have an Actuals version called 'Actuals', Budget Version called 'Budget'. The amounts are clearly defined per period, per version (actuals/Budget) in our data table, the problem is when we bring the data into power BI we are unable to display in the required format.

One possible solution is that i could create 24 measures, i don't feel this is best practice as we will also have forecasted data coming through going forward.
The DAX formula i used to did not work, i unsuccessfully tried to obtain ytd actuals and full 12 months budgeted data, however, once combined with periods from Date_Dim produced invalid results.
Possibly something could be done in SQL to create different measures for each period actuals/budget but once forecast data comes in then it will be problematic have many different measures.


Do you have a separate Calendar dimension? If you do and you put month or whatever on one axis, then this should work fine.
